# Custom Attribute to read the value and property

Tags: c#, .net-core

I trying to create a custom Attribute to read a property and a value, here is the code, anyone knows how I can do this?

```
private string reason;

[CustomAttribute]
public string Reason
{
    get
    {
        return reason;
    }
    set
    {
        // Read the reason and the value to the attribute
        reason = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing it? Seems like a X Y problem

Comment: What do you mean, return the value to the attribute? Attributes are just meta data?

Comment: No not returning any values, depending on the values I receive I will then log some information.